# DNS requests over ICS (Internet Connection Sharing)

Tags: python, dns, twisted

Recently i implemented i small captive portal in python. i redirect users to the login page from dns requests. All worked fine until i realised when dns server i manually change on client system to a public dns, it totally bypass the captive portal. My problem is, how to redirect users even with dns servers changed or how to block all outgoing dns requests which is not using the default dns.

I was thinking listening on port 53 would capture all request using twisted.
This is a very simple example of how i am doing it:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor`

class UDP(DatagramProtocol):
    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, addr):
        print datagram, addr

port = 53
max_byte = 512

reactor.listenUDP(port, UDP(), '', max_byte)
reactor.run()
```

Am i doing it wrong?

I also tried to block remote port 53 from the firewall on the main machine providing Internet connectivity but it also doesnt work.

Comment: DNS is a large issue in captive portals. In general you need to have it working even when the user is not logged in. If the  user for example wants to connect to `stackoverflow.com` it has to get the right IP address on the first attempt. If he doesn't the browser will not show the captive portal or be having problems later redirecting to the page. This requirement for working DNS allows several techniques to break out of the captive portal. But to list them all and how to counteract would be far beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: @Klaus I handled that part already and works fine. But i just don't know how to go about the dns in windows. In linux everything is simple with iproute table

Answer (score 0):

If users are bypassing your captive portal by changing DNS, the issue is that they can route DNS requests *around* the portal, and therefore there's nothing you can do *in* the portal.  You need to create routing rules which redirect all port 53 traffic on your network to your DNS server, regardless of where they're trying to send it.

The bad news is, you can't do this with Twisted.  You need to do this in your router's operating system, using something like iptables.

Comment: Thanks @Glyph, i guessed the same thing. But how to reproduce iptable like rules in windows?